# Outlook changes html on office Add-In

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I try to write an outlook plugin that inserts a link into the email body. I want to give the link a style in order to look as a button, to give the user a more engaging experience.

The issue I got, is that outlook changes the style on the  elements, and the inline style I put on that element is getting lost.

I am inserting the HTML as shown below:

```js
var tablePref = '<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;"><tr><td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 10px 18px;background:\'';

var backgroundColor = 'green'; //The color is user-given, I put green as an example

var tableSuf = '\'"><a href="https://somelink.com" style="text-decoration:none">Some text</a></td></tr></table>'


var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

item.body.setAsync(tablePref+backgroundColor+tableSuf,
  { 
    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, 
    asyncContext: {} 
  },
  function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status ==   Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)
    {
      //Show error dialog
    }
    else 
    {
      //Successfully set data in item body.
    }
  });
```

I get the link on the email successfully, and it looks just right, but when I send the email, the HTML structure of this button looks like this instead:

```html
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background: 'green';">
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-element: frame; mso-element-frame-hspace: 2.25pt; mso-element-wrap: around; mso-element-anchor-vertical: paragraph; mso-element-anchor-horizontal: column; mso-height-rule: exactly">
          <a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <span style="text-decoration: none">Some Text</span>
          </a>
          <!-- o ignored -->
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Outlook is changing my a elements, and this causes that mail clients render the  element with a line below because the style got overridden. Is there any way to avoid Outlook change my HTML or it is a known bug? This is happening across all platforms (OWA, Outlook for Mac 16.21 and Outlook for Windows)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you please confirm where you are using your add-in and composing your email ? Outlook desktop (windows) or outlook web (online) ?

Comment: It is true that Outlook may change the html depending on the level of HTML support on the editor.  Using your specific example, I sent a message to myself using Desktop Outlook for Windows and the content looks the same during compose and read. It would be helpful if you can confirm the client you are sending and the client you are using to read. Screenshots would help too.